# nodeJS Agenda library - start jobs on server start

Tags: node.js, cron, job-scheduling

im using agenda library (https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda/)

I can create and run jobs correctly, but i need to start jobs when i start the server.

I do it this in a module:

```
 var startAlerts = function(){

        log.debug('alerts', 'launching alerts');
        console.log('alerts', 'launching alerts');

        var agenda = new require('agenda')({
            db: {
                address: db.serverConfig.name + "/" + db.databaseName,
                collection: 'alerts'
            },
            processEvery: '24 hours',
            maxConcurrency: 250
        });

        agenda.start();
    };

    startAlerts();
```

But the jobs dont start..What im doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: can you show how does your jobs looks like? also processEvery: '24 hours' means that agenda will update schedule once per 24h

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://goo.gl/5sCNBM It shows you the setup and a suggests a project structure.